# Using UniversalImageLoader with authorization

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

In my app, some of images are protected by authorization layer.

Downloading process is:

1. Try download image from uri
2. If failed on authorization get authorized uri and try again.

The problems are:

1. There are no retry method, so I cannot try again with new uri
2. Images are cached by uri (?) so I cannot save image from authorized uri as it was from base not authorized uri, so my authorized images will always be redownloaded.

Is there any way to resolve it in some simple way?

Comment: hey if you see the code at https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader and will enhance accordingly for retry and redownloading of images than hope you can solve problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement your own `ImageDownloader` (it's better to extend `BaseImageDownloader`) which will handle this case. It should check if auth is required and it is then it makes re-query.

Comment: Additionally I extended `HashCodeFileNameGenerator` to returns same names for all uris for the same image (not authorized and all authorized). Unfortunately I am not able to do the same for memory cache, but it is not most important for me for now.

Comment: Yes, you can not change memory cache key generation mechanism yet. This feature is planned to release in near future.

Answer (score 0):

```
loader.displayImage(beans.get(position).getImagePath(), holder.imageView, options,
                new ImageLoadingListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                        //try again here with another URI.

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
```

Comment: There is no method for trying again. If I will call again `displayImage` I will lost all parameters except for uri (I'd like generic method). Furthermore image won't be loaded from memory/disk because uri would change.

Comment: which parameters will be lost?. It'll automatic cache your image from your URI to memory card

Comment: There is about 5 arguments for this method, in your example options will be lost (you can't access options from listener). It will be cached under authorized URI, so everytime I want to display it, loader will try to download, would fail, try again and download under new authorized uri